# grep for repeated values from pattern list

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have file A.txt which is a lists of unique ids (column 1) and its corresponding values(column 2):

A.txt

```
ABC1D_T1_B1  123.4
ABC2D_T1_B2  146.7
ABC3D_T1_B1  567.8
ABC4D_T0_B2  96.8
ABC1D_T0_B1  145.9
```

Second file is B.txt, not unique but has duplicated entries

```
ABC1D_T1_B1
ABC1D_T1_B1
ABC2D_T1_B2
ABC3D_T1_B1
ABC3D_T1_B1
ABC4D_T0_B2
ABC1D_T0_B1
ABC1D_T0_B1
```

How can I grep B.txt from A.txt and report the values of col 2 for the repeated list

Result:

```
ABC1D_T1_B1  123.4
ABC1D_T1_B1  123.4
ABC2D_T1_B2  146.7
ABC3D_T1_B1  567.8
ABC3D_T1_B1  567.8
ABC4D_T0_B2  96.8
ABC1D_T0_B1  145.9
ABC1D_T0_B1  145.9
ABC1D_T0_B1  145.9
```

Normally if unique entries are there in B.txt then

```
grep -Fw -f B.txt A.txt >Result.txt
```

How can I do this for multiple repeating entries using grep?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have also tagged `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == NR {a[$1] = $0; next}; {print a[$1]}' A.txt B.txt
```

I don't think a single `grep` can do this, but a combination of `xargs` and `grep`:

```
xargs -I{} grep -Fw -- {} A.txt < B.txt
```

Comment: @Steph curious: does the `-w` improve things? (I know OP is using it, but I am not sure if it's needed.)

Comment: @muru, without it, `ABC1D_T1_B1` would match `ABC1D_T1_B10`. That's a bit better with `-w`, though `ABC1D_T1_B1` would still match `ABC1D_T1_B1.2`

Answer (score 5):

You could do it by using a simple `join`:

```
join A.txt B.txt
```

But, in order to work both files must be sorted on the join key (here the first (blank separated) field). To do it, just use `sort -b filename`.

Comment: Never thought that it could be so simple by just using join! Thanks Much!